# Which crown is best for growing each stat as party members gain levels?

Tags: final-fantasy-the-4-heroes-of-light

Which crown is best to wear for increasing each character stat: HP, Strength, Intellect and Spirit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Leveling with a given crown equipped does not affect stat growth as you level](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/961297-final-fantasy-the-4-heroes-of-light/answers?qid=231487).** Characters have base stats and equipped crowns modify current values by fixed multipliers.

The crowns with the highest effects on given stats when equipped are:

- HP: Paladin
- Strength: Dark Fencer
- Intellect: Black Mage
- Spirit: White Mage

See the [FF wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy:_The_4_Heroes_of_Light_Crowns) and [the relevant, albeit incomplete FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/961297-final-fantasy-the-4-heroes-of-light/faqs/61505) for more information on the stat effects of the various crowns.